# AtributeError: module "pytube" has no attribute "YouTube"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm try to use pytube but most of the times y use the command pytube.youtube or I try to import YouTube from pytube I have an AttributeError.

```
import pytube

video = pytube.YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pTwQKMrTt0')
formatos = video.streams.all()

print('Formatos disponibles:')
for i in formatos:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Your code prints a bunch of `<Stream: ...>` objects on my machine. Did you properly install pytube?

Comment: @Jeppe I instlled it ussing "pip install pytube" and I have reinstalled it making sure there were no mistakes.

Comment: @Jeppe Thanks for your help, I have commeted a silly mistake, I have create a document called pytube.py so when I import pytube the program import my program.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import pytube
```

to

```
from pytube import YouTube
```